# How do I remove this broken thumbturn bathroom lock?

Tags: lock

Our bathroom door lock doesn't work and I'm trying to replace it. But I can't understand how to take it off. There don't seem to be any screws to unscrew and everything seems to be stuck firm.[image]

[image]

Comment: There might be a allen screw at the bottom, same as the metal ring shows at top of picture.  Need an allen wrench or a hex bit screwdriver to undo.

Comment: @crip659 No I don't think there is one.

Comment: There is a notch in the ring.  Might be a place to push in a hidden pin or pry off with a screwdriver.

Comment: Ok I'll try that. Thanks

Comment: As @crip659 suggested, try a utility knife blade between the shell and tab shown in your second picture on the right side of the trim. If the trim pops loose then the next question is how to get the slotted non-knob off. It might be held by a spring or retaining clip under the trim.

Comment: Looks to me like the bottom piece has a trim ring that can be pried off.

Comment: Thanks guys. Prying it off worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are either setscrews as on the hardware above you have not noticed (certainly your pictures fail to show where they would be) or the latch knobs unscrew (likely with some effort as they have been in place for some time, and may have threadlocker applied to prevent nuisance-loosening) by using a screwdriver/coin on the external knob while holding the internal one, and then the trim prys off, shaft pulls out, etc. Heat may help with any threadlocker.

Then again, applying a (padded) wrench to the handle or a screwdriver (perhaps aided by a wrench) to the exterior knob might return it to working without removal, if it just needs to be moved and then lubricated.

If the maker is evil, the screw might be left-hand-threaded, but that seems unlikely since it's a non-secured application.

It's also possible that it's a straight press fit and just has to be pried off. Given no brand-name marking it seems difficult to look up.

Comment: There's definitely no setscrews. I'll try unscrewing the knobs themselves. Thanks

Comment: Yeah prying off worked. Thanks